# What is the recommend way to arrive at AngularJS 1.5.+, with LiveReload when upgrading from 1.3.7?

Tags: angularjs, upgrade, livereload, wakanda

I have a Wakanda 10, community version, solution that uses AngularJS 1.3.7, and it does not yet use LiveReload.

I want to upgrade to Wakanda 11, community version,AngularJS 1.5+, with LiveReload.

What is the simplest way to do this?

I understand that I may have to do coding changes.

Should I download the Wakanda 11, community version, and start a new project with it that has LiveReload built-in, and then copy my Project into it and debug?

Answer (score 3):

In order to upgrade your application you have two face two different problematics:

**A) Upgrade AngularJS from 1.3.7 to 1.5.x.**

This step is pretty straight-forward. It's necessary to replace your AngularJS library inside your application with the version you desire.
If a `bower.json` is included in your application (and it should be since we are speaking of a Wakanda scaffolded application) then you can modify the following lines:

```
"dependencies": {
  "angular": "~1.4.4",
  "angular-wakanda": "~1.0.4"
}
```

and run in terminal from the folder of the application the command `bower update` to do it automatically.

Update `angular-wakanda` to the latest compatible version.

*Please note that you are upgrading minor versions of AngularJS and probably also angular-wakanda. Minor changes in API and methods can be present and break your application.*

**B) Add live-reload to your application**

Many efforts have been done in the latest Wakanda Studio versions to achieve agnostic compatibility with different scaffoldings. Adding live-reload to your Wakanda application means adding a standard live-reload kit as you normally do with web applications.

It can be made with Gulp, Webpack, Grunt, Browserify. Wakanda Studio would try to run any environment.

Since the *angular-wakanda + Gulp* live-reload environment is the one included in the actual scaffolding, I suggest you to start with it as follows:

1. In the `package.json` file add the following `devDependencies`:

   ```
   "devDependencies": {
     "gulp": "^3.9.0",
     "gulp-connect": "^2.2.0",
     "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.9.0",
     "minimist": "^1.2.0"
   }
   ```
2. In order to trigger `gulp`, add to the same files the following `scripts` to your `package.json` file:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "serve": "gulp serve",
     "start": "npm run serve"
   }
   ```
3. Create or copy from an existing Wakanda solution the `gulpfile.js` file. You can copy [this gulpfile.js](https://jsfiddle.net/stuttufu/xfau23hq/) if you prefer a more generic approach than the actual included in the base solution. It's important to adapt the configuration parameters to your actual application scaffolding if necessary:

   ```
   var defaultOptions = {
     default: {
       serverUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081',
       port: 8000,
       livereloadPort: 35729,
       app: 'app/',
       output: 'app/',
     }
   };
   ```
4. Finally re-open the solution and click `Run Page`. This should trigger an `npm install` and an `npm start`, which will trigger `gulp serve` which will enable live-reload.

Please note that the implementation can have minor configuration differences depending on the Wakanda Studio version you are using. I suggest you to always update to the latest available.

For a deeper understanding on Wakanda Studio build process I also suggest you to check out [this tutorial](https://wakanda.github.io/wakanda-studio/build-process-introduction.html) which also explain how to add SASS precompilation to the application.